# Why I can't download 11.2.1

Tags: xcode

I previously installed 11.2 but with the bug known of `UITEXTVIEW` , I had to rollback to 11.1. Now I found that 11.2.1 was released I can't find it on https://developer.apple.com/download/
Any solutions? Also it doesn't appear on app store updates. 
  My OS is Catalina 10.15.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're looking under the Release tab, not the Beta tab?  Or use [this link](https://developer.apple.com/download/release/).

Comment: huh I don't know what to say after 10 hours of working I seem a little stupid. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a release version, You can:

1. Download from [**AppStore**](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)
2. Direct download from [**Apple developers portal**](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_11.2.1/Xcode_11.2.1.xip)